# Focus on textbox inside gridview and updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

After breaking my head over something apparently simple, here I am:

I have an ASP.NET `GridView` wrapped inside an `UpdatePanel`. Once the user enters something in the last textbox of the last row and moves out, I add a new row to the gridview. This is done server-side by firing the `OnTextChanged` event of the textbox and setting its `AutoPostBack` property to true. This bit is Ajaxified by using the `UpdatePanel`.

My simple requirement is: **I need to set the focus on the first textbox of the newly added row once the partial refresh is over**.

What I tried:

```
//Get the newly added row (basically the last row)
GridViewRow newRow = myGridView.Rows[myGridView.Rows.Count - 1];
//Get the TextBox control on which I want to set focus
TextBox textBox = newRow.FindControl("txtMyCode") as TextBox;
//Set the focus
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).SetFocus(textBox);
```

On stepping through the code, each of the above lines execute, and yet, when the partial postback completes, the textbox doesn't have the focus. The `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page)` returns an instance of the `AjaxControlToolkitScriptManager`, which is there on the Master page.

Any ideas?

Comment: How have you added the row and where/when? Try to use `RowDataBound` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could write jquery to achieve this bit if  you were not able to set focus from server site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(BindEvents);

function BindEvents() {

    //write your logic here lets say 
        //if your grid view empty row is visible then set focus


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript pageLoad function which is Ajax-specific function fired every time the content of ajax update panel is refreshed. Inside that function trigger 'focus' on your text box.

```
function pageLoad() {
document.getElementById('ClientIdOfYourTextBox').focus(); }
```

You need to get ClientId of newly added text box in javascript. You can achieve it by saving it in hidden field server-side once it's added and then get hidden field's 'value' client-side or by building jquery expression (e.g. get last from all 'input' controls with id containing 'txtMyCode')